# Circuit analysis homework - LTspice results are different from calculations

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, homework

Original question:
[image: Original question]

I have already tried calculating it, but after simulating the circuit in LTspice, the answer is different.

My working is shown below.

I've included a screenshot of the LTspice showing a Vout of about 118 mV whereas I calculated 1.163 V.

Where is my mistake, please?

[image: My LTSpice schematic and the Vo it shows]

[image: My working pt. 1]

[image: My working pt. 2]

(Original copy of working is at:  https://notability.com/n/1r9BP36Zt507ijpb2LnVdc
(Scroll down to page 12))

Comment: For the future, LTspice accepts `m` as `milli`, `n` as `nano`, `k` as `kilo`, etc, so you can avoid writing the values as `0.00...0047`, which is hard to read, and write, instead, `47n`. Also, if you need accurate frequency analysis then your best bet is to use the `.AC` analysis, not `.TRAN`. For a single frequency use `.ac list <frequency_value>` (e.g. `.ac list 100`). Don't forget to use labels for nets (`F4`) so that the readings are much easier.

Comment: Thankss! I tried it but I keep getting 0 Vo, here's a snap https://imgur.com/a/N881vrS

Comment: For some reason imgur won't open it, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfuV.png) is how it should look like. You can also use the `.step` command for more than one frequency, or add more frequencies in the list: `.ac list 100 1k 10k 100k`.

Comment: ooohh, myh bad, i was using the voltage source in sine mode, got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your complex arithmetic:-

[image]

@100Hz

I get

Za = 4.7000e+03 + 6.2832e+01i

Zb = 2.2000e+03 - 3.3863e+04i

Zc = 1.0000e+03 - 1.5915e+05i

Zp = Za || Zb = 4.5887e+03 - 5.6789e+02i

Vo = 4 * Zp/(Zp + Zc) = 0.0182 + 0.1143i

|Vo| = 0.1157V

Comment: Thanks! But can you please tell me what that e is? I don't understand that representation. It doesn't look like exponential form of complex numbers either. Also why is Vo = 4 * Zp/(Zp + Zc)?                                                                                                                                                                  Edit: Just realised thats the voltage divider rule.

Comment: 4.7000e+03 +6.2832e+01i = 4700 +  j * 62.832    It's a commonly used notation.  

4V is the input voltage and the rest is just the voltage divider equation.

Comment: Thank youuuuu!!!

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea about the last part? Here's my graph for part b https://imgur.com/a/ays3kTe

Comment: Since you have already entered it into LTspice, I suggest running an AC analysis. With linear y axis you should get something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/7Dl6XBs.png)

Comment: Yup, thanks. thats what my graph looks like in 5b. But 5c asks about filters, I did some googling and realised that there are multiple types of filters, but none of them match the graph.

Comment: It is a high pass filter, a little "weird" ...

Answer (score 4):

In case you need all others answers for verifying ... Maple sheet.

[image]

And this for the last question ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There's 1 thing I dont understand. For 100Hz, we got 0.1157V which is ther in your answer, but there's another set of complex number before that, 0.01822042999 + 0.11427...I. What is this?

Comment: On lines, First number is the complex answer (a+jb), after you find modulus and then phase in degree ... the answer you want (modulus) is for 100 Hz -> 0.1157228760, then  80.94... degree.

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense thanks!